# Django: Formatting DateTimeField fields in JSON Serializer

Tags: python, json, django

I have a model that has a few DateTimeFields and TimeFields, and I am serializing them to JSON using:

```
json.dumps({'items': list(items.values('id','date_time','time'))},cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

But the items list shows the date_time field as date_time": "2013-12-25T17:00:00".

How do I impose my own formatting for date_time or any DateTimeField/TimeField/DateField that gets JSON serialized?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pre-process the fields in `items` that need your own formatting using [strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime). May be something like:

```
now = datetime.now()
desired_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M'
item['date_time']= now.strftime(desired_format)
```

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing something like that, but with a list, like:

items_list = {'id': items.id,'date_time': a_function_to_format_datetime(items.date_time),'time': a_function_to_format_time(items.time)}

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own json encoder, look at the [DjangoJSONEncoder](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/json.py#L84). Instead of `isoformat` you can use `strftime`.